# How to pass value to maven pom.xml at rum time from java file?

Tags: maven, tags, runtime, pom.xml

I have a java file where a variable taken value at run time.I search for a service using web service discovery and keep its url in a variable.
Now I need to pass this value to pom.xml.

abc.java has code with

```
String url= http://xx.xx.xx.xx:55939/ABCDevice?wsdl
```

Pom.xml is:

```
<wsdlOptions>
           <wsdlOption>
           <wsdl>url</wsdl> <!-- get urlvalue from java file -->
            <wsdlLocation>classpath:com/admin/discovery/ABCService.wsdl
                </wsdlLocation>
            </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
```

In wsdl i want to pass string value "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:55939/ABCDevice?wsdl" which is determined only after run time.

How can i do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider this as an Apache Maven specific issue, but a general Java issue (Maven probably made you aware of it).
During build-time you have no idea what the url should be. Depending on the type of application you have several options:

- JNDI (in case of a webcontainer)
- A properties file on a predefined location
- System properties
- As arguments (in case of executable jar)
- Adjust web.xml before deploying (some webcontainers can help you with this)
- ...

In you use a framework like Spring there are easy ways to inject one the options above.

Comment: Thanks Robert but these option would have helped when my abc.java was called before pom.xml .  Since my maven command mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.admin.discovery.WSClient" will call pom.xml first , Can we create some dependency that this pom.xml is called after some action performed(java class execution?)  Thanks

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, I wouldn't use `exec:java` to run the class. Instead I would generate an executable jar, probably with http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html If you still want to use the exec-maven-plugin, add `-Dexec.arguments=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:55939/ABCDevice?wsdl` and pass its value to the right class.

Comment: I have to use maven as it is a mandate in my project. How would adding this argument help me pass wsdl url ? As this url will be formed in the java class itself after a set of steps performed in method getwebservice(). I dont know what this url is until i go in abc.java()

Comment: I still don't get the problem. Is `String url= http://xx.xx.xx.xx:55939/ABCDevice?wsdl` hardcoded in the java-file? If not, how do you get its value right now?