# Maven how to set properties visible in java

Tags: java, spring, maven

This is my profiles in pom.xml:

```
<!-- Production Profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>profile</name>
                <value>prod</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
        </properties>

    </profile>

    <!-- Development Profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <!-- Integration Test Profile -->
    <!-- Use mvn -Dprofile=test -->
    <profile>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>profile</name>
                <value>test</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Used to locate the profile specific configuration file -->
            <build.profile.id>test</build.profile.id>
            <!-- Only integration tests are run. -->
            <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
            <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Next in my spring context configuration file i have got :

```
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/app-${profile:dev}.properties")
```

So that tricks allow me run my project using different configuration. I have got also 3 configuration properties files,and in that file there is :

```
spring.profiles.active=integration-test
spring.profiles.active=prod
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

This configuration work perfect. Active profiles is change as i expect so for example when i run `mvn clean install -Dprofile=test`, i am using `app-test.properties` file and my active profile is `integration-test`.

**But this trick have got one issue. When someone run mvn install -Pintegration-test then active profile is dev not integration-test. So it is possible run `mvn install -Pintegration-test` and then set property profile to test ??**

Comment: when you say active profile is something, do you mean spring profile or maven profile?

Comment: Yes. Spring found no value for ${profile}  that's why its default value 'dev' is picked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use Maven Profiles per environment. With Maven you build the jar/war/ear. A different environment shouldn't result in another artifact. So instead you should pull the configuration outside this artifact. [How to pass value to maven pom.xml at rum time from java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931181/hoe-to-pass-value-to-maven-pom-xml-at-rum-time-from-java-file) describes a lot of options how to solve this.

Comment: "You shouldn't use Maven Profiles per environment.", indeed he SHOULD do, but not this way :). Difference, as eis said, is that Spring profiles are not Maven profiles. Confusion come from that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `-P+integration-test` option