# How can I get profile specific pom properties in web.xml in Spring?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml, web.xml

I am using a service in my spring project.I have following code in my web.xml:-

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>prerenderServiceUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>http://10.0.0.45:3000</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I have 3 profiles in my pom.xml: staging,development & production:
I am looking for the best practices to get <**my.service.url**> in my web.xml:

```
<profile>
    ...
        <properties>
                ...
<my.service.url>http://10.0.0.45:300</my.service.url>
          ...
        </properties>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the maven resources plugin's filtering function what you need: (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Maybe you can consider to store environment specific variables in the target environment, not in your build scripts/properties and you can load it from the classpath during the startup. Tight coupling your environment settings with your pom.xml adds some extra effort to you to update your build settings every time when the environment changes or new servers added.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can use profiles, they shouldn't be used in this case. The idea is that you can distribute the same war over and over again and that the configuration is pulled in. Read [How to pass value to maven pom.xml at rum time from java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931181/hoe-to-pass-value-to-maven-pom-xml-at-rum-time-from-java-file) for all the options.